# Write value in next available cell csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a code of writing peoples names, ages and scores for a quiz that I made. I simplified the code to write the names and ages together and not separately but I cant write the score with the names as they are in separate parts of the code. The CSV file looks like this

```
name, age, score
Alfie, 15, 20
Michael, 16, 19
Alfie, 15,    #After I simplified
Dylan, 16,
```

As you can see i don't know how to write a value in the 3rd column. Does anyone know how to write a value into the next available cell in a CSV file in the column 2. I'm new to programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Michael

Comment: What do you want to fill in the values in the third column? method `fillna` can help you?

Comment: I just want to append a value into the next available cell in the column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Alfie','Michael','Alfie','Dylan'], 'age':[15,16,15,16], 'score':[20,19,None,None]})
```

Out:

```
  name   age score 
0 Alfie   15  20.0 
1 Michael 16  19.0 
2 Alfie   15  nan 
3 Dylan   16  nan
```

if you need read csv to pandas then use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Your_file_name.csv')
```

I suggest two ways to solve your problem:

1. `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)` fill all (this example fill 0).

Out:

```
  name   age score 
0 Alfie   15  20.0 
1 Michael 16  19.0 
2 Alfie   15  0.0 
3 Dylan   16  0.0
```

2. `df.loc[2,'score'] = 22` fill specific cells

Out:

```
  name   age score 
0 Alfie   15  20.0 
1 Michael 16  19.0 
2 Alfie   15  22.0 
3 Dylan   16  nan
```

If, after that you need write your fixed data to csv, the use:

```
df.to_csv('New_name.csv', sep=',', header=0)
```